# Can redshift be used to create an accurate accelerometer in a phone?

Tags: optics, kinematics, speed-of-light

Currently, accelerometers use small springs which produce wild fluctuations and inaccuracies.

Because light's speed is limited and compresses when its source moves in the direction it's going, and decompresses when it does the opposite, it seems we could use light as a spring which uses the constraints of space as its medium.

What I'm wondering is if a cross-beam of light were put inside of a device, with receivers constantly reading the frequency of the light to detect its red-shift compared to what the output should be, would this be accurate enough to determine the phone's velocity and acceleration in space?

Comment: There are optical ring accelerometers, but those use phase shift, not red shift.

Comment: And if you want to avoid 'wild fluctuations', use a better grade of accelerometer - some of the MEMS ones are quite good (note that the proof mass does not move much).

Answer (score 0):

You can measure rotational velocity very accurately with a [fiber optic gyroscope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibre_optic_gyroscope). When you are rotating, the path length along one direction "is shorter". Whether you consider that a red shift or a phase shift doesn't really matter - you are using the finite speed of light to determine the rotation.

Measuring absolute velocity in space is of course impossible (because it's dependent on your reference frame). Acceleration could be measured using the same principle as above, but it's not easy.

I found a nice description of an experiment to measure velocity using interference in [this paper](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/582/1/012041/pdf) which claims an accuracy of velocity on the order of µm/s. Unfortunately, they are moving one mirror in their setup relative to the rest of the interferometer - that's a much more favorable setup than a self-contained device (and explains why they are able to measure velocity and not just acceleration).

Comment: "Acceleration could be measured using the same principle as above, but it's not easy." - So in answer to the OP's question, it's probably going to be a long, long time before we see built-in optical ring accelerometers/gyroscopes in an iPhone. Maybe something to look forward to in the iPhone 53s.